# Modifying/overwriting NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

A series of binary NumPy arrays representing cloudy (1's) and clear (0's) sky pixels I added together to find number of observations where cloud is present in each pixel. I want to find percentage of cloud `number of cloud (1's)/total observations*100` but cannot get this to work in Python using NumPy arrays as I want to modify original variable:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1,0,1])
arr2 = np.array([0,0,1])
total1 = np.add(arr1, arr2)
>>> [1 0 2]

total2 = total1                  #Purely to make multiple to elaborate my issue
variables = [total1, total2]

for x in variables:
     x = x + 100

total1
>>> [1 0 2]
```

`total1` variable has not updated. It works with:

```
for x in variables:
    x += 100

total1
>>> [201, 200, 202]
```

I however do not want to increment by 100. I want to calculate percentage like:

```
for x in variables:
    x = x / 1 * 100             #I have simplified the maths for ease of  reading

#This is my desired output - note how total1 is updated, not created
total1
>>> [100, 0, 200]
```

But this does not work. I am accessing the variables in this way for n variables (variable names go from `total1` > `total*n*`).

Comment: Have a look at numpy and its arrays. This is a perfect use case.

Comment: I do not understand your comment? I am using NumPy arrays and it is not working? Please elaborate?

Comment: Can you clarify your code? I think the problem is that you are doing a shallow copy when you wanted to do a deep copy. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Could you give the desired output of your example?

Comment: In what format do you input the series? Because it might be easier, to calculate it directly on the input, if you have it in 3D.

Comment: I have updated the example code. The input is essentially >800 binary masks as NumPy arrays which I have created. I have added different ones together, by date, to give total1, total2, total3... for n days. I want to update the 'total' variables so that they are now percentages instead of values representing number of cloudy observations. I hpoe this helps!

Comment: Yes, thanks. Is there any way to get access to the binary masks directly, before you save them to somewhere? Or is your RAM limited and you HAVE to process everything slice by slice?

Comment: Well and x/=(1*100) works equally well.

Comment: Thank you that final suggestion worked a treat! Had to change the percentage sum slightly but this worked fine. I think there is an issue with updating NumPy variables in the way which I listed and incrementing the original variable is the only way to do it. I have worked it out now using /= so thank you very much for that!

Comment: Still: If you want to do that performant, your approach is most likely not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help! Can you further explain why this is not ideal? I'm relatively new to Python so I may be overseeing something simple. Is it due to this method being inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create the arrays, add them together and divide each element by 100. For the percentage, you need to know the number of entries. You could work with a 3-D array and using numpy's sum/average etc. functions.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,0,1])
b = np.array([0,0,1])
c = (a+b)/100
```

if you can arange your input to be a 3d Stack of images (just a wild guess), you can do something like:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,1]])
b = np.array([[0,0,0,],[0,1,0],[1,1,1]])
c = np.empty((2,3,3))
c[0]=a
c[1]=b

d = (c.sum(axis=0)/c.shape[0])*100
```

This can of course be made much simpler depending on the input. I just put it here, to show each step.

Comment: Thank you - I am aware of this method, I was just wondering if I can do the whole thing without creating a new variable 'c', in your case, each time. Do you have any ideas as to whether this is possible?

Comment: Well, you need to address your output somehow. If you want to do the stuff in-place, just don't name it c, but a :)

Comment: Thanks for your help - I understand your example and I know that replacing 'c' with 'a' will overwrite the values in 'a', but the issue I have described persists when I do this using the 'for x in variable' method noted in my question. The 'x' does not update - I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well, this is a question of scope. You assign x in the for-loop. I'll add another answer to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the adding to work in-place:

```
for i in range(len(variables)):
  variables[i]+=100
```

should do the trick. Note, that doing something like this is highly inefficient.

Comment: Thank you Dschoni again, but please read the original question. I am aware of the incremental adding/subtracting to update the variable (I have explained this in the original question), but I am wanting to overwrite/update the original variable to replace the number of observations with a percentage instead. This does not work using the += or -= (or similar) method.

Comment: This sets variables[i] to whatewer you want it to be. You can do variables[i]=variables[i]*2+1 e.g.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using an empty indexing to access the array data underneath the variable like so:

```
a = np.arange(5)
b = np.arange(5)*2

vars = [a, b]
for x in vars:
    x[:] = x + 100
a
>>> array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104])
```